# How to create RSA xmlstring using public and private key in c#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, rijndael

How can i create RSA xml string as below if i know the private and public key (both in string format) in c#.Output should be in below format

```
 <RSAKeyValue>  
   <Modulus>…</Modulus>  
   <Exponent>…</Exponent>  
   <P>…</P>  
   <Q>…</Q>  
   <DP>…</DP>  
   <DQ>…</DQ>  
   <InverseQ>…</InverseQ>  
   <D>…</D>  
 </RSAKeyValue>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Use the bouncycastle c# library.

Comment: What sort of string do you have?

Comment: @bartonjs...i can store both private and public variable in string variable in c#

Comment: @bartonjs..keys are in below format
MIGgMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GOADCBigKBggC8rLGlNJ17NaWArDs5mOsV6/kA
7LMpvx91cXoAshmcihjXkbWSt+xSvVry2w07Y18FlXU9/3unyYctv34yJt70SgfK
Vo0QF5ksK0G/5ew1cIJM8fSxWRn+1RP9pWIEryA0otCP8EwsyknRaPoD+i+jL8zT
SEwV8KLlRnx2/HYLVQkCAwEAAQ==